# URL Rewrite IIS and Glassfish from port 8080 to 80

Tags: java, iis, glassfish

I'm running a glassfish server that handles all jsp and servlets.

Now there is a way to get it working so that you can run IIS on port 80 and glassfish on port 8080, now the problem is:

When i request `http://localhost/myWebApplication` it should rewrite the url and use `http://localhost:8080/myWebApplication`

Basically I make a request to IIS, but the response I get back must be from Glassfish.

When I request the url with port `8080` it works, because its getting it from Glassfish, but i need to go through IIS to Glassfish.

Here is a website that explains it all: http://jstoup.wordpress.com/2012/04/25/how-to-integrate-glassfish-with-iis/

but I still can't get it working.

I have got no idea how my url rewrite rules must be set up.

Answer (score 1):

This is James from the blog you referenced.  If you haven't gotten this working you may have to enable your server farm as a proxy.  If you select your web farm there should be a proxy config in the center console.  All you should have to do is turn that on and you should be good to go.  Let me know if you've got any problems